# How does R handle Unicode / UTF-8?

Tags: r, unicode, utf-8

If I write

```
`Δ` <- function(a,b)   (a-b)/a
```

then I can include `U+394` so long as it's enclosed in backticks. (By contrast, `Δ <- function(a,b) (a-b)/a` fails with `unexpected input in  "�"`.) So apparently R parses UTF-8 or Unicode or something like that. The assignment goes well and so does the evaluation of eg

```
`Δ`(1:5, 9:13)
```

. And I can also evaluate `Δ(1:5, 9:13)`.

Finally, if I defined something like `winsorise <- function(x, λ=.05) { ... }` then λ (`U+3bb`) *doesn't* need to be "introduced to" R with a backtick. I can then call `winsorise(data, .1)` with no problems.

---

The only [mention](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-devel/R-ints.html#Encodings-for-CHARSXPs) in R's documentation I can find of unicode is over my head. Could someone who understands it better explain to me — what's going on "under the hood" when R needs the <kbd>`</kbd> to understand assignment to ♔, but can parse ♔(a,b,c) once assigned?

Comment: In the R-internals:

What R users think of as variables or objects are symbols which are bound to a value.

I think the CHARSXP section you linked to is the value, and you are actually interested in the rules for symbols.

That said, I've worked on R code written in Chinese, so I'd expect delta to work.

Comment: What version of R are you using/what OS/what locale?  I get "Error: \uxxxx sequences not supported inside backticks (line 1)" when assigning a function to `Δ` (Tested on the today's R-devel and 3.1.0 under Win 7, English UK locale.)

Comment: What version of R are you using that `Δ <- function(a,b) (a-b)/a` fails? And when you say it "fails", what do you mean? Do you get a syntax error? If worked for me on `R version 3.1.0,  x86_64-apple-darwin10.8.0 (64-bit)` locale en_US.UTF-8

Comment: @MrFlick @RichieCotton 3.1.2 "Pumpkin Helmet", says `Error: unexpected input in "�"`.

Comment: Δ doesn't work for me on `R version 3.1.1 (2014-07-10) Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)`

Comment: @RichieCotton MrFlick Sorry, too late to edit that comment. Also using 32-bit Ubuntu, Irish English locale. Seems like a lot of the people getting errors are using 64-bit, I wonder if that's it?

Answer (score 4):

I can't speak to what's going on under the hood regarding the function calls vs. function arguments, but [this email from Prof. Ripley](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2008-May/163497.html) from 2008 may shed some light (excerpt below):

> R passes around, prints and plots UTF-8 character data pretty well, but it translates to the native encoding for almost all character-level manipulations (and not just on Windows). `?Encoding` spells out the exceptions [...]

The reason R does this translation (on Windows at least) is mentioned in [the documentation that the OP linked to](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-devel/R-ints.html#Encodings-for-CHARSXPs):

> Windows has no UTF-8 locales, but rather expects to work with UCS-2 strings. R (being written in standard C) would not work internally with UCS-2 without extensive changes.

The R documentation for `?Quotes` explains how you can sometimes use out-of-locale characters anyway (emphasis added):

> **Identifiers consist of a sequence of letters, digits, the period (.) and the underscore.** They must not start with a digit nor underscore, nor with a period followed by a digit. Reserved words are not valid identifiers.
>
> **The definition of a letter depends on the current locale**, but only ASCII digits are considered to be digits.
>
> Such identifiers are also known as syntactic names and may be used directly in R code. Almost always, **other names can be used provided they are quoted**. The preferred quote is the backtick (`), and deparse will normally use it, but under many circumstances single or double quotes can be used (as a character constant will often be converted to a name). One place where backticks may be essential is to delimit variable names in formulae: see formula.

There is another way to get at such characters, which is using the unicode escape sequence (like `\u0394` for Δ). This is usually a bad idea if you're using that character for anything other than text on a plot (i.e., don't do this for variable or function names; cf. this quote from [the R 2.7 release notes](https://svn.r-project.org/R/branches/R-2-7-branch/src/gnuwin32/CHANGES), when much of the current UTF-8 support was added):

> If a string presented to the parser contains a \uxxxx escape invalid in the current locale, the string is recorded in UTF-8 with the encoding declared.  **This is likely to throw an error if it is used later in the session, but it can be printed, and used for e.g. plotting on the windows() device.**  So "\u03b2" gives a Greek small beta and "\u2642" a 'male sign'.  Such strings will be printed as e.g. `<U+2642>` except in the Rgui console (see below).

I think this addresses most of your questions, though I don't know why there is a difference between the function name and function argument examples you gave; hopefully someone more knowledgable can chime in on that. FYI, on Linux all of these different ways of assigning and calling a function work without error (because the system locale is UTF-8, so no translation need occur):

```
Δ <- function(a,b) (a-b)/a         # no error
`Δ` <- function(a,b) (a-b)/a       # no error
"Δ" <- function(a,b) (a-b)/a       # no error
"\u0394" <- function(a,b) (a-b)/a  # no error
Δ(1:5, 9:13)        # -8.00 -4.00 -2.67 -2.00 -1.60
`Δ`(1:5, 9:13)      # same
"Δ"(1:5, 9:13)      # same
"\u0394"(1:5, 9:13) # same

sessionInfo()

# R version 3.1.2 (2014-10-31)
# Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)

# locale:
# LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8    LC_NUMERIC=C                LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8
# LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8  LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8     LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8
# LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8    LC_NAME=C                   LC_ADDRESS=C
# LC_TELEPHONE=C          LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8  LC_IDENTIFICATION=C

# attached base packages:
# stats  graphics  grDevices  utils  datasets  methods  base
```

Comment: Thanks for doing all this research. I had no idea there was such a significant difference between Windows and Linux as far as UTF-8 goes, but that explains the people who commented with failures. (And I'm glad to know it's less likely 32-bit-ness than Windows-ness causing their errors.)

Comment: thanks @isomorphismes. I've just edited it slightly to make it more coherent, but the same basic information is there. In sum: any unicode-related weirdness is almost always the fault of Windows, but it's nothing to do with 32 vs 64 bit. It's all about UTF-8 vs. UCS-2 (FYI, if you do further reading, UCS-2 is also known as "UTF-16LE with BOM").

Comment: @isomorphismes Under R 3.1.2 (Win 7 64 bit) `get("Δ")(1,2)` will execute without error

Answer (score 3):

For the record, under R-devel (2015-02-11 r67792), Win 7, English UK locale, I see:

```
options(encoding = "UTF-8")

`Δ` <- function(a,b) (a-b)/a 
## Error: \uxxxx sequences not supported inside backticks (line 1)

Δ <- function(a,b) (a-b)/a
## Error: unexpected input in "\"

"Δ" <- function(a,b) (a-b)/a      # OK

`Δ`(1:5, 9:13)
## Error: \uxxxx sequences not supported inside backticks (line 1)

Δ(1:5, 9:13)
## Error: unexpected input in "\"

"Δ"(1:5, 9:13)
## Error: could not find function "Î”"
```

Comment: OK interesting. I wouldn't have expected this to differ across versions.