# Displaying UTF-8 encoded characters in R

Tags: r, utf-8, rodbc

I am using the `RODBC` package to read data from SQL server. R is reading the Chinese characters as "?????" 
I have passed the parameter `DBMSencoding = "UTF-8"` to the `odbcConnect` function.

Following is the sample code I am using:

```
Connection <- odbcConnect("abc", uid = "123", pwd = "123", 
                          DBMSencoding = "UTF-8", readOnlyOptimize=T)

Var1 <- sqlQuery(Connection, query, errors = TRUE, stringsAsFactors=F)
```

May be I didn't pass the arguments the way I am supposed to?

```
sessionInfo()
R version 3.2.3 (2015-12-10)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 7 x64 (build 7601) Service Pack 1

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252    LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                           LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] RODBC_1.3-12

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] tools_3.2.3

odbcGetInfo(mainConnection)
         DBMS_Name               DBMS_Ver        Driver_ODBC_Ver      Data_Source_Name            Driver_Name 
        "Microsoft SQL Server"  "10.50.4000"     "03.52"                                         "SQLSRV32.DLL" 
        Driver_Ver               ODBC_Ver            Server_Name 
      "06.01.7601"           "03.80.0000"
```

Comment: Did you try without specifying `DBMSencoding`? Unicode might be default.

Comment: Yes, I did. I included the parameter only when the default wasn't working.

Comment: Does `DBMSEncoding="UCS-2"` do any better?

Comment: Nope. The data doesn't get read, at all. It gives this error: 
    Error in iconv(query, to = enc) : 
  embedded nul in string: 'þÿ\0S\0E\0L\0E\0C\0T\0

Comment: Correction: When I don't specify DBMSencoding - only the chinese characters are not read.

Comment: Ok. No `DBMSEncoding`, French ok, Chinese broken. More information about your setup will be helpful. Please share the output of `sessionInfo()`, and would you please share the output of `odbcGetInfo(connection)`, and the data types of the text columns from `sqlColumns(connection)`.

Comment: @pneumatics: Kindly find attached the link in the beginning of the post

Comment: The column in question is "Stringvalue"

Comment: Thanks for providing that information. Editing the question to add it would be helpful, so others don't need to click a link, and for posterity so that people coming by later can know the situation. Is `StringValue` the only column with non-English words in it?

Comment: Yes,     StringValue is the only column with non-english words in it.

Comment: Are you having this problem in RStudio?

Comment: Yes, I am using RStudio.

Comment: Would you please try to replicate the problem using an R shell? You can open one with the Tools --> Shell ... menu.

Comment: I get the same error when running through R console.

Comment: Did you prefix the "StringValue" field with `N` when it was inserted?

Comment: I am afraid I don't know how to do that.

Comment: Can you share the SQL DDL statement that was used to insert this data into SQL Server? If you don't prepend the strings with N, like `N'中華民族'` instead of a bare string constant like `'中華民族'`, then you may not get the correct characters back out.

Comment: @pneumatics: I too am unaware of how the data was inserted in the SQL server. What I know for sure is when the data was retrieved in Excel, the values showed up just fine.

Comment: Ok, that it works in Excel is helpful information.

Comment: @Sumedh Regarding *Error in iconv(query, to = enc) : embedded nul in string: 'þÿ\0S\0E\0L\0E\0C\0T\0 *: **There is an open bug in R that prevents UTF-16/UCS2 conversions under certain conditions** (which may be the case here): https://bugs.r-project.org/bugzilla3/show_bug.cgi?id=16737

Answer (score 2):

Check the database's character encoding:

```
select userenv('language') from dual;
SIMPLIFIED CHINESE_CHINA.AL32UTF8
```

Change your Environment Variable `NLS_LANG` before connecting to the database:

```
Sys.setenv(NLS_LANG="SIMPLIFIED CHINESE_CHINA.AL32UTF8")
Connection <- odbcConnect("abc", uid = "123", pwd = "123", DBMSencoding = "UTF-8", readOnlyOptimize=T)
```

Answer (score 1):

R on Windows has a lot of problems *displaying* characters outside of ASCII, even though it is often faithfully representing them internally. There is a lot of information in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28494252/1664024) about why this is the case, and some simple diagnostics in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32487771/1664024). First try plotting, like:

```
# first, make sure plotting Chinese works in general
# (i.e., you have an appropriate font)
hanzi <- "漢字"
plot(1, 1, type="n")
text(1, 1, hanzi)
```

If that works, replace the `hanzi <- "漢字"` line with your sql query line to get some Chinese text from your database into a string variable, and try plotting that. If it shows up on the plot, then the characters are being *read* fine and represented internally fine, and the problem is just *displaying* them in the console. If plotting worked for the "漢字" string variable but doesn't work for your SQL-extracted string, then at least you know that the problem is actually with the SQL part and not just with display in the console.

Comment: Thank you for sharing this approach. It seems like the problem is with the SQL part.

Comment: @Hack-R, any suggestions on how to improve? Though the data is retrieved fine in Excel when using SQL, it is retrieved as `????` in R.

Comment: @Sumedh I don't know. I just thought you were saying it's a SQL problem not an R problem. I use Chinese data but I don't have this problem if the encoding is correct.

Comment: Hey All, I am currently facing the same issue as reported by the OP , this thread seems to be the latest on this issue. Any solutions on this please ?

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem and successfully solved it. It was quite simple. Go to Control Panel --> Region and Language --> Administrative --> Change system locale --> Chinese.