# Non-Latin characters show as question marks when using rodbc/odbc/dbplyr with SQL-Server

Tags: r, sql-server, utf-8, odbc, dbplyr

I'm using dbplyr to get data from SQL-Server into R, but Chinese, Japanese and other non-Latin characters are appearing as "?". I'm using a windows machine.

I've read through the following threads:

- [How does R handle Unicode / UTF-8?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28483441/how-does-r-handle-unicode-utf-8/28494252#28494252)
- [How to use Regex to strip punctuation without tainting UTF-8 or UTF-16 encoded text like chinese?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32451109/how-to-use-regex-to-strip-punctuation-without-tainting-utf-8-or-utf-16-encoded-t/32487771#32487771)
- [Fetching UTF-8 text from MySQL in R returns “????”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12869778/fetching-utf-8-text-from-mysql-in-r-returns)

These provide some useful ideas, but nothing has worked so far. I have tried:

- Setting `encoding = 'UTF-8'` within the `dbConnect` function. Characters still show as question-marks.
- Setting `encoding = 'UTF-16'` within the `dbConnect` function. R returns an error: `# Error in iconv(x[current], from = enc, to = to, ...)`
- Changing the global character encoding to UTF-8 with: `Sys.setenv(LANG = "UTF-8")`
  and `options(encoding = "UTF-8")`
- Checking if the characters display when plotting (which would indicate that they are being stored correctly). This wasn't the case.

I was able to get the characters to display correctly by using RJDBC, however this is not compatible with dbplyr, according to this [GitHub issue](https://github.com/tidyverse/dbplyr/issues/98).

Here is my session info:

```
> sessionInfo()
# R version 3.5.0 (2018-04-23)
# Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
# Running under: Windows >= 8 x64 (build 9200)

# Matrix products: default

# locale:
# [1] LC_COLLATE=English_United Kingdom.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United Kingdom.1252    LC_MONETARY=English_United Kingdom.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                           
# [5] LC_TIME=English_United Kingdom.1252
```

My code looks like this:

```
> con <- dbConnect(odbc(),
                   Driver   = "SQL Server",
                   Server   = "server name",
                   Database = "database name",
                   user     = "my username",
                   password = "my password",
                   encoding = "UTF-8")
```

odbc/dbplyr sure handles these character types on Windows, so what am I missing here?

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: How are you passing these characters to SQL Server? SQL Server 2017 and prior don't support UTF-8 either.

Comment: Are you sure the encoding is UTF-8? Windows typically uses Latin-1 encoding.

Comment: @larnu The characters appear properly when I query the database directly in SSMS (i'm not sure if i can fully answer your question as I'll have to ask around in my team!)

Comment: @MrFlick  This has been a confusing point for me. Some places suggest that the default windows encoding is Latin1, others say GB 1252, or similar. I'm new to character encodings, so I probably have some misconceptions .  From the threads I've read it sounds like UTF-8 is what I need to see Chinese/Japanese characters properly

Comment: Certainly UTF-8 is the wrong choice. 2019 was the first version to support UTF-8.

Comment: I suggest to load sample of data from SQL to csv file (check encoding of csv file and if data is not corrupted with ? symbols). If everything is good, try to load data in R from this file.

Comment: @gofr1 this would be a good option although in the long term I'll really need to pull data from the sql server directly

Comment: @larnu I'm told the SQL server uses 'Latin1_General_CI_AS'

Comment: @MaxL Just check it.

Answer (score 0):

Check the list of encodings available with `iconvlist()`.
I used `encoding = "windows-1252"` to be able to work correctly with Nordic characters using ODBC version 1.2.2.

Although I have not used Chinese or Japanese characters, the encoding values "GB18030", "gb2312" and "GBK" could be used for Chinese Guobiao for example.

wikipedia has a helpful [page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_encoding) (scroll to the bottom for the list).