# Cross-OS character encoding issues causing difficulties in MATLAB and R

Tags: r, windows, macos, matlab, character-encoding

I use a Windows PC in the Office, a MacBook at home, and a Linux PC in the lab (I have my reasons in each case). I use Dropbox to synchronise my code across machines. Occasionally, I have cause to use a slightly unusual symbol in my code. For example, plotting a graph in R using a degree sign (`°`). If I save the file on the Mac and open it on the PC, the character has now rendered as '`Â°`'. If I change this back to the `°` symbol on PC, when I return to the MacBook, it renders as a '`?`', and R refuses to run the code.

This is not exclusive to R; I have noticed this in MATLAB as well, often with similar characters. These just happen to be the two languages I do most of my work in. I understand that this probably has something to do with file encoding, but I have no idea how to make sure (at least for R and MATLAB) that I save in a compatible format. Avoiding the use of these characters is obviously one option, but is hardly ideal.

Is there a solution to this issue, either universally, or at least for R and MATLAB?

Comment: Is there no way to enforce UTF-8 encoding on all of your files on all machines?

Comment: find other ways of representing those characters `plot(0, main = expression(100~degree~C))`

Comment: @MichaelChirico, that's perhaps what I'm looking to achieve. If there is some way to enforce UTF-8, I'd like to hear it!

Answer (score 1):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28494252/1664024) explains a lot about why getting UTF-8 to work with R on Windows is difficult (UTF-8 is default for R on Linux, and I think on Mac too). The safest and easiest path is probably to use unicode escape codes (like `\u00B0` for the degree sign) in your scripts. That way your code will always be ASCII-compliant but the symbols should still render when plotting. The answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4984532/1664024) should get you sorted for MATLAB (i.e., using `feature('DefaultCharacterSet', 'UTF8')` in your MATLAB startup file).